# unable to render the map in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

In my code i'm trying to get the current location on map with its lattitude & longitude.But while running the code i get the lattitude & longitude of current location but unable to render the map in eclipse.And the following error gets generated everytime.Although i have generated API key also.

```
11-27 12:09:47.910: E/b(31763): Authentication failed on the server.
11-27 12:09:47.910: E/Google Maps Android API(31763): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
11-27 12:09:47.930: E/Google Maps Android API(31763): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
11-27 12:09:47.930: E/Google Maps Android API(31763): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
11-27 12:09:47.930: E/Google Maps Android API(31763): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
11-27 12:09:47.930: E/Google Maps Android API(31763):   API Key: AIzaSyBRkcj0dLxxhmjAC6W6TaCoxFo3vCTHQYI
11-27 12:09:47.930: E/Google Maps Android API(31763):   Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): C9:40:D9:B6:BD:13:27:8A:98:38:29:FD:EA:AC:AF:48:AB:86:FA:E6;com.example.gpstracker
```

Comment: do your tried by uninstall and install your app?? some times it work

Comment: yes i have tried this but it didnt worked.

Comment: What about you API key on  google console, cross check once again and confirm  all are fine

Comment: API key is also correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32503686

Comment: yes i have also followed these steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.blugz.maffy2"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<permission
android:name="com.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.maps.mapss.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission       android:name="com.example.googlemaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
 <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
      <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

      <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyBRkcj0dLxxhmjAC6W6TaCoxFo3vCTHQYI"/>

      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
   <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     </application>

      </manifest>'
```

/
add this on your manifest and make sure you added  **google-play-service_lib**. on your project as library

Comment: I did everything in this way only.